# Can I pass a struct to a function and have it translated to multiple parameters?

Tags: function, coldfusion, struct, arguments

In ColdFusion, is there any way to pass in a struct of parameters to a function with multiple optional parameters?

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
<cfset myResults = myFunction(myStruct) />

<cffunction name="myFunction" ... >
   <cfargument name="myArg1" type="numeric" required="no" default="" />
   <cfargument name="myArg2" type="string" required="no" default="" />
   <cfargument name="myArg3" type="numeric" required="no" default="" />
.....
</cffunction>
```

Where "myStruct" has a random combination of key-value pairs - for example, "myArg3":222 and "myArg2":"hello".

Is this possible, or do I have to specifically list each argument (with a check of "isDefined" for each one)?

Comment: NB: the : separator for key:value pairs in structs is undocumented in ColdFusion, you should use key=value instead

Comment: @duncan - I was just describing the contents of the struct, not writing actual code

Comment: On that note, I would add that using `:` as a separator in ColdFusion 9 and before wasn't supported, but it has been announced that it will be supported in ColdFusion 10 and beyond (yet to be released at this writing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I haven't tested this yet, but I just realized I might be able to do this using a `<cfinvoke argumentCollection="#myStruct#">`. Will try that now...

Edit:
This did work! And Sergii's suggestion for my original syntax without a cfinvoke works as well.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax for you. Please note that you can do the same for another invokation type, like this: `<cfset myResults = myFunction(argumentCollection=myStruct) />`

Comment: You can do the same with custom tags and "attributecollection". In fact, as of CF9 (or was it 8?) the built-in tags can take a structure in "attributecollection".